# Iterate through grouping with a query used in argument to linregress

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have grouped a dataframe called "full_df2" by the "filter" column. Then I put the distinct 'filter' group names in a list called "unique_list". I want to iterate through my dataframe with the following code so that I can get a plot for each grouping. 'Rating' and 'hhs' are the columns in my dataframe that I will run the regression on.

When I run the code below, I get this error.
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
I've tried adding .split(',') at the end of line 2, but it doestn't help.
I've been surfing through boards trying to get past this error. I'm new to Python. So, any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Here's some sample data and the real code I used.

```
    full_df2 = np.array([['Letter', 'Sync', 'Status', 'filter', 'Rating', 'hhs'],
                ['A', 'And', 'Off', 'A And Off', .4, 300],
                ['A', 'And', 'On', 'A And On', .5, 300]
                ['A', 'Or', 'Off', 'A Or Off', .7, 300]
                ['A', 'Or', 'On', 'A Or On', .3, 300]
                ['A', 'Between', 'Off', 'A Between Off', .6, 300]
                ['A', 'Between', 'On', 'A Between On', .4, 300]
                ['A', 'And', 'Off', 'A And Off', .6, 400],
                ['A', 'And', 'On', 'A And On', .4, 400]
                ['A', 'Or', 'Off', 'A Or Off', .3, 400]
                ['A', 'Or', 'On', 'A Or On', .4, 400]
                ['A', 'Between', 'Off', 'A Between Off', .3, 400]
                ['A', 'Between', 'On', 'A Between On', .8, 400]
                ['A', 'And', 'Off', 'A And Off', .4, 250],
                ['A', 'And', 'On', 'A And On', .5, 250]
                ['A', 'Or', 'Off', 'A Or Off', .7, 250]
                ['A', 'Or', 'On', 'A Or On', .3, 250]
                ['A', 'Between', 'Off', 'A Between Off', .6, 250]
                ['A', 'Between', 'On', 'A Between On', .4, 250]
                ])

    unique_df = dict(tuple(full_df2.groupby(['Letter', 'Sync', 'Status', 'filter'])))
    unique_list = ([x[-1] for x in unique_df])
    for x in unique_list:
       print (x)


for p in unique_list:
  slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['rating']], full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['hhs']])
  filter_df = full_df2.query("filter == @p")
  ax = sns.regplot(x="rating", y="hhs", data=filter_df, color='b', 
  line_kws={'label':"y={0:.1f}x+{1:.1f}".format(slope,intercept)})
  ax.legend()
  ax.set_title(p)
  plt.show() 
  print(slope)
```

This is the complete error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-75511dada630> in <module>()
      1 for p in unique_list:
----> 2     slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['rating']], full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['hhs']])
      3     #result = [stats.linregress(data[key]['num'],data[key]['com']) for key in keys]
      4     #slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err =
      5     #.split(',')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_mstats_common.py in linregress(x, y)
     91 
     92     # average sum of squares:
---> 93     ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
     94     r_num = ssxym
     95     r_den = np.sqrt(ssxm * ssym)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the data? and the full error message to see exactly where it's occurring...

Comment: What happens if you print line 2 rather than assigning it?

Comment: @QusaiAlothman I added a sample of the data and the full error message.

Comment: @ncfirth I get the same exact error when I try to print rather than assigning it.

Comment: That is odd. I always try flattening my inputs to numpy arrays can smooth over some errors, can you try `full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['rating']]` -> `full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['rating']].values` for both the inputs?

Comment: @ncfirth Hmm. I think you're on the right path. I checked the shape of  `print(full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['rating']].shape)` and it's (53,1). I tried adding `.values` but it was still the same shape.

Comment: If you add `.flatten()` as well?

Comment: @ncfirth This is so perfect!!! I used `full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['rating']].value.flatten()` and `full_df2.query("filter == @p")[['rating']].value.flatten()` and it worked!!! Thank you so much!!!. Will you post as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our comments above, the problem that you have is the shape of your input. The simplest way for you to make it work is to change the input of `linregress` to this:

```
stats.linregress(full_df2.query("filter == @p")['rating'], full_df2.query("filter == @p")['hhs'])
```

Personally I'd write it the following way though:

```
stats.linregress(full_df2.loc[full_df2.filter == p, 'rating'], full_df2.loc[full_df2.filter == p, 'hhs'])
```